# How can i erase a part of a single path?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

[image]

'A' is Represent for a Drawn Path And 'B' Is For Represent After Erase Little Part From this Path ,,

**My Question is::** 
How Can i erase a single path (not from any list, just a Particular Part From a Single Path) like 'B' From Pic?..

Code For drawing Path is below :

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){

        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            path.moveTo(event.getX(), event.getY());
            x=event.getX();y=event.getY();
        }else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){
            path.quadTo(x,y,(event.getX()+x)/2, (event.getY()+y)/2);
            x=event.getX();y=event.getY();
        }else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
            path.lineTo(event.getX(), event.getY());
        }

        return true;
    }
    public void update() {

    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas){
        super.draw(canvas);
        canvas.drawPath(path,paint);

    }
```

Comment: Why are you **shouting**?

Comment: How did you intend to specify what to remove?

Comment: Bro, I want to remove a little part prom drawn Path like 'B' on the picture ..

Comment: *Let me clarify:* How did you intend to specify what to remove, i.e. how "little" a part do you want to remove? 1 pixel? 10 pixels? 5%? What?

Comment: Bro.. Please check my image .. [link] (https://www.dropbox.com/s/orbtr4g1yhspn2r/eraser.png?dl=0)

Comment: ***Bro!!!*** I did check your image *in the question*. All I see is a `B` image with "some" part removed. No indication of **how much**!! Which is why I've been asking (twice): *How did you intend to specify what to remove?* I still don't see an answer to that *in the question*.

Comment: oooo.. sry bro.. i intent to remove 5% or 10 pixels , but Ill happy with Both example  Bro..

Comment: Well, then, you should **edit** the question to clarify that, don't you think?

Comment: Yea I think ..  Tnx Bro.. @Andreas

Comment: Just call `canvas.drawPath(pathToErase, paintSetToWhite)`

Comment: @Jon tnx bro.. I solve the problem myself .. I used PathMeasure.getSegment() function to erasing ..